# Как заблокировать окна Diagnostic Traces и DrvmCDB?

Tags: windows

При запуске системы появляются два окна: `Diagnostic Traces` и `DrvmCDB`. Пока их не закрыть, они не исчезают и как их отключить неизвестно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определите место, где установлена DLA. Обычно это что-то вроде C:\Program Files\Sonic\DLA. И выполните в консоли две команды:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Sonic\DLA\install
ssdsetup -u
```

Перезагрузите компьютер.